# Xcode 11 Simulator stops Responding to text events

Tags: ios, ios13, xcode11

I have recently updated to Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a). I am generally stuck on textfield events on the simulator. I cannot type anything. When I switch to other apps like safari, reminder same behaviour is observed. The app does not crashes.

Is anyone else facing this? Anyway to get through

Comment: I observe this problem since Xcode 10. Only rebooting of the Mac computer seems to help.

Comment: I also had the same issue. For me, a `Hardware > Restart` was able to resolve the problem.

Comment: For me restarting simulator helps for the time :(